# Static Site Generation Using dynamic routes in nuxt2

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, pre-rendering

I am trying to do the static site generation but when I run the `yarn generate` command then it creates all other routes & adds them in the dist folder but in the case of my dynamic routes like `pages/accommodations/_id.vue` not automatically add it in the dist folder. Even I try with `nuxt.config.js` with this code for one accommodation. It makes the route but does not add it to the dist folder & sometimes it will add it in the dist folder & show error of `maximum call stack size exceeded`

```
generate: {
fallback: true,
routes() {
  return [
    '/nl/accommodations/maison-sumiane'
  ]
}
```

},